# Python - How to return a different value when using a class 'get' method?

Tags: python, class, variables

I want to overwrite the get method for a variable in a class.
(I'm not sure how to explain it otherwise.)

I've tried looking on Google, but nothing really helped me.

My code:

```
class Class():
    self.foo = ['foo','bar']

print(Class().foo)
```

I want to make it so it will print out `' '.join(Class().foo)` by default instead of just `Class().foo`.

Is there something that you can add to the code to make it like that?

Comment: you want `print(Class().foo)` print 'foo bar'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `__getattribute__` to do that:

```
class Thingy:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ['huey', 'dewey', 'louie']
        self.other = ['tom', 'jerry', 'spike']

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'data':
            return ' '.join(super().__getattribute__(attr))

        else:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)

print(Thingy().data)
print(Thingy().other)
```

Output:

```
huey dewey louie
['tom', 'jerry', 'spike']
```

Python 2 version:

```
class Thingy(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ['huey', 'dewey', 'louie']
        self.other = ['tom', 'jerry', 'spike']

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'data':
            return ' '.join(super(Thingy, self).__getattribute__(attr))

        else:
            return super(Thingy, self).__getattribute__(attr)

print(Thingy().data)
print(Thingy().other)
```

Note that it is easy to get into infinite loops with overriding `__getattribute__`, so you should be careful.

There's almost certainly a less scary way to do this, actually, but I can't think of it right now.

Comment: Hmm... that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @ProfessorDragon What doesn't work, specifically?

Comment: Well, it just prints this: ['huey', 'dewey', 'louie'] and ['tom', 'jerry', 'spike'].

Comment: @ProfessorDragon Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Yes. (I need the comment to be more characters so I'm adding this.)

Comment: @ProfessorDragon That's the problem; my code was written for Python 3. I have edited my answer to include a Python 2 version that should perform as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the `@property` wrapper instead of defining `foo` as an attribute.  You can store the parameters you want to print in a private class variable and then define the behavior of the `foo` to return the string join.

```
class Class:
    _foo = ['foo', 'bar']

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return ' '.join(self._foo)

print(Class().foo)
# prints:
foo bar
```